# How do I mix Excel's dynamic array syntax with normal row references in the same formulae?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

How do you mix Excel's dynamic array formulae with normal row formulae, e.g in this formula:
=IF(tblAnalysis[Type]="sell",tblAnalysis[Price]-MIN(**Y2#**,**tblAnalysis[Price2]**),MAX(**Y2#**,**tblAnalysis[Price2]**)-tblAnalysis[Price])*10000

I am using a MAX and MIN, but I want those formulae to apply to the value in cell Y2 and the value from tblAnalysis[Price2] for that row and apply relatively for each row, in other words it should take the miminum of 2 values; but instead it calculates the minimum of the Y column and the table column Price2, for each row containing this formula.

I have tried this version also, but this does not give the right results either

=IF(tblAnalysis[Type]="sell",tblAnalysis[Price]-MIN(**Y2**,**tblAnalysis[@Price2]**),MAX(**Y2**,**tblAnalysis[@Price2]**)-tblAnalysis[@Price2])*10000

Comment: Sample data and the expected result might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `IF` Formula Example When Mixing a Spilled Array and Structured References

- It is assumed that the spilled array (column `Y`) is in one column and has the same number of rows as the number of data rows in the table.

```
=MAP(tblAnalysis[Type],tblAnalysis[Price],tblAnalysis[Price2],Y2#,
LAMBDA(a,b,c,d,IF(a="Sell",b-MIN(c,d),MAX(c,d)-b)*10000))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect VBasic, thank you very much! @BigBen, I would attach some data if you still want it just for illustration (let me know), but VBasic's solution is spot on.